# What is the best way to declare classes in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

What is your preferred way to define JavaScript classes, and why?

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Could you be a little more specific about what you're after?

Comment: I beg to disagree even if this gets me in hot water. A question like this is valid and should be answered as the poster may indeed want to learn best practice.Here is one:http://frugalcoder.us/post/2010/02/11/js-classes.aspx, and definitely should look into YUI, or  Crockford (http://www.crockford.com/

Comment: @mozillanerd: The question was phrased in such a way that the answers would be subjective, which the faq http://stackoverflow.com/faq describes as not the type to ask. If there was some particular pattern or patterns that OP had a question about, then the question should be specific to that.